# Python PubSub pull request pulls very few messages

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have set the max_messages that can be pulled by the subscription to 10,000 but for some reason every time my python file pulls from PubSub the number of messages is below a 100, which is too few. Please help me understand how I can pull more messages as I need to process around 10,000 messages per pull.

```
subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
with subscriber:
    pullData = subscriber.pull(
        request={
            "subscription": subscription_path,
            "max_messages": 10000,
        },
        retry=retry.Retry(deadline=300),
    )
```

Comment: You can create a streamingpull to have more performances when you read messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The number of messages is affected by the message size and other factors that Google determines. 50 or 100 is a typical number for most services.